# Как в sharpdevelop читать и писать в файл .settings, который лежит в проекте?

Tags: c#, settings, properties, sharpdevelop

В Visual Studio есть `Properties.Settings.Default` и управление пользовательскими настройками прямо из свойств проекта.

В sharpdevelop таких удобств нет, но можно создать файл `someName.settings` вручную `Add -> New item -> Misc -> Settings`. Собственно вопрос, как проще всего к нему обратиться, чтобы не изобретать велосипеды. Допустим там у меня объявлена переменная `string someVar = "some value"`. Как ее прочитать, перезаписать и сохранить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак метод научного тыка принес результат. Оказалось, что в sharpdevelop файл anyname.settings это просто удобный интерфейс для добавления хранимых параметров (такой же как в окне свойств проекта visual studio), причем их (таких файлов) может быть много.

Так при создании файлов `foo.settings` и `bar.settings` в проекте `testapp` и заведении туда переменных bar и foo соответственно в `app.config` появляются новые ветки, которые выглядят так:

```
 <userSettings>
    <testapp.foo>
        <setting name="bar" serializeAs="String">
            <value>barValue</value>
        </setting>
    </testapp.foo>
    <testapp.bar>
        <setting name="foo" serializeAs="String">
            <value>fooValue</value>
        </setting>
    </testapp.bar>
 </userSettings>
```

И теперь в коде можно делать так:

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //читаем значение
        string barVal = foo.Default.bar; // barValue
        //или так
        barVal = foo.Default.Properties["bar"].ToString(); // barValue

        //меняем значение
        foo.Default.bar = "New bar value";

        //сохраняем параметры в реестр (будут доступны при следующих запусках приложения)
        foo.Default.Save(); 

        //опять читаем
        barVal = foo.Default.bar; // New bar value

        //получаем значение по умолчанию
        barVal = foo.Default.Properties["bar"].DefaultValue.ToString();  // barValue

}
```

Все то же самое справедливо для второй ветки:

```
string fooVal = bar.Default.foo; // fooValue
```

Кстати, после компиляции все из `app.config` проекта, в том числе дефолтные значения наших параметров попадает в  `testapp.exe.config` который должен лежать по умолчанию в одной папке со скомпилированным `testapp.exe`.

Надеюсь, кому-то будет полезно.